# mongoose find objectId case error

Tags: mongodb, casting, mongoose, find

Getting a `ObjectId` casting error. Trying to find documents title of a content.

```
var mongoose=require('mongoose');
var Schema=mongoose.Schema;

var contentSchema = new Schema({    
    language: String,
    genres : String,
    title : {
        type: [String],
        required: true
    },
    cast : {name : [String]} ,
    storyline : String,
    videoUrl : String,
    path : String,
    contentType : String,
    duration : String,
    rating : String,
    tvCardImageUrl : String,
    tvBgImageUrl : String,
    mobileCardImageUrl : String,
    mobileImageUrl : String,
    tabletCardImageUrl : String,
    tabletBgImageUrl : String,
    publishedDate : Date,
    uploadedDate : Date,
});

module.exports=mongoose.model('contents',contentSchema);

router.route('/content/card').get(function(req, res){   
    Content.find({language: 'English'})
    .select('title')
    .exec(function(err, content){
        if(err)
            res.send(err);
        res.json(content);
    });

});
```

**Error**

```
"message": "Cast to ObjectId failed for value \"card\" at path \"_id\"",
"name": "CastError",
"kind": "ObjectId",
"value": "card",
"path": "_id"
```

Can you please let me know how to cast returned ObjectId?

Comment: Add _id: String in the Schema file still didn't work

Comment: Returned null object

Comment: @JohnnyHK After change to String it worked. My bad I was passed worg id that's why it return null object. Thanks Johnny.

Answer (score 0):

You appear to have a document in your collection with an `_id` of `"card"`. That value can't be cast to an `ObjectId` which results in the error.

If your docs' `_id` values are strings (opposed to the default `ObjectId`), you need to specify that in your schema. If so, add `_id: String` to your schema.